# symfony2 multiple firewall error with login_check

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have a symfony 2 app, with normal members and admin area, but for some reason, i can't get the admin area login part to work. Read all the questions here about the theme and try them but none of them worked for me.
The initial problem i think, is the check route is not behind the firewall, so symfony security not recognise it.

my security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: sha512

firewalls:
    alogin:
        pattern:  ^/admin/login$
        security: false
    main:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        provider: in_memory
        form_login:
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            login_path: /admin/login
            default_target_path: /admin/list
        logout:
            path:   /admin/logout
            target: /admin
    main:
        pattern:    ^/(?!admin)
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /
            failure_handler: public.failed_login_handler
            success_handler: public.success_login_handler
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true


providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_VIP:         ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_VIP
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Without the main firewall, it's working, with it, i got 404 for the /admin/login_check.

Comment: You have 2 firewalls with the same name `main` - its a typo?

Comment: Jeeez, yes, that was the problem.., thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem that you have 2 firewalls with the same name `main`. Firewall must be with unique name.